# IPython Widgets Separated by Character Rather Than Word

Tags: python, pytorch, ipython, google-colaboratory

As you can tell in the picture below, the table is separated by characters rather than full words.

```
def apply(f):
    text = f
    text = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text)
    res = LM().check_probabilities(text, topk=20)
    l = str(res)
    paraphrase_widget = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=l,
    description='Paraphrases',
    disabled=False,
    layout= widgets.Layout(width='100%')
   )
    display(paraphrase_widget)
    return {"result": res}


apply("In order to")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is from the given screenshot. What is your expectation based on the code? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the link: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RNhhw9vmEu_zhMQSHd9I4SNr6bodx6Xn?usp=sharing) I'm sorry for explaining the issue so poorly. If you notice, however, the widget reads: "b", "p", "e" instead of "bpe_strings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in unpacking pytorch's prediction and passing those results to the widget in proper format (a list of tuples). Here's how you can do that:

```
# Modify your widget to the following
paraphrase_widget = widgets.SelectMultiple(
      options=res['pred_topk'][2],
      description='Paraphrases',
      disabled=False,
      layout= widgets.Layout(width='100%', height="300px")
   )
```

---

*Here's what this looks like for me:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is perfect.

Comment: Happy programming! @zbush548